# Log rotation with compression

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have very old application deployed in Linux server. We are using the `RollingFileAppender`  which is deleting the old logs due to disk space problems.

Whenever we get a problem in the application most of the logs won't available in the disk. If we compress the log files, we can keep 100 log files in place of one uncompressed log file.

Is there a way to compress the file once the log file is filled up and delete them after certain point of time *[lets say a week.]*

I tried with `DailyRollingFileAppender`, but it is not working the way we are expecting.

Maximum logs limit is 500. But the application creates 200 logs per hour. The actual logs which contains the error messages may not be available for us. So we are planning to zip all the log files and delete them after one week of time.

Comment: have the shell script zip the logs every night , and then move them to a secondary storage device

Comment: "it is not working the way we are expecting"... so tell us what you *were* expecting, and how `DailyRollingFileAppender` differs from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, kindly check this [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/index.html). It has support for that. 
Add this to RollingFileAppender configuration.

```
<appender...>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/wombat/foo.%d{yyyy-MM}**.gz**"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if log4j supports this, but if you move to logback you have this possibility.

http://logback.qos.ch/

Hajo

Answer (score 0):

yes, a shell script or a cron http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5  would fix your problem quite easily

Comment: There is an existing tool on most Unix servers: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html